# How do I interpolate variables into a string?

Tags: ruby, string

I am trying to add two variables together with a space between them:

```
errors = [[lot_count, '#{attribute}: #{error}' ]]
```

When I display this I see : `#{attribute}: #{error}`

Any ideas why it's not giving me the variable's value?

Comment: This isn't a Rails problem, it's a basic Ruby string interpolation problem.

Comment: Have you tried using double quote marks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Single quotes in Ruby are not interpolated, whereas double quotes are:

```
"#{attribute} #{error}"
```